# Javascript for loop variable not working

Tags: javascript, loops, for-loop, onclick

I am having a problem with my for loop inside a javascript function. The variable `i` is not working as an argument for the function `showAlbum(i)`. Why is that happening?

```js
var out = "<table>";
for(i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            out += "<tr><td><a href=''onclick='showAlbum(i);' >"+
                arr[i].artist +
                " - " +
                arr[i].title +
                "</a></td></tr>";
        }
out += "</table>";
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because `i` wrapped in quotations is the literal character *i*, not the value held within your `i` variable. You need to evaluate it outside of the quotations:

```js
out += "<tr><td><a href=''onclick='showAlbum(" + i + ");' >"
```

Comment: Thanks for the short and well explained answer.

Answer (score 4):

The `i` is within the string literal, so variables are not parsed from the string.

Break out of the string like so:

```
out += "<tr><td><a href=''onclick='showAlbum(" + i + ");' >"+
//                                           ^^^^^^^^^
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the formatting to:

```
var i,
    out = '<table>';
for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    out += '<tr><td><a href="" onclick="showAlbum(' + i + ')" >' +
        arr[i].artist +
        ' - ' +
        arr[i].title +
        '</a></td></tr>';
}
out += '</table>';
```